# As an iOS developer, how do I provide design specifications for my UX/UI designers?

Tags: designers

Some background, I'm an iOS developer making an app for my startup company. I've been working with two UX/UI designers for the last couple months, but it's all been very informal discussion on how to decide what they want to design.

Typically we sit together, discuss what functionality the development side and business side wants for the app, and helping them just understand what it is we're trying to make and if they can come up with a design to match our functionality.

As our startup is beginning to scale into more fast-paced operations this year, I owe it to my designers to be more formal about how to give them their future assignments. I've done few research and seen things like [Creative Brief] but I was wondering if there's any way to give them assignments since I'm already very comfortable with them and they already are on-board my team.

I come from an electrical engineering industry background where when we used to develop new products, we had an engineering specifications document with:

Background, Scope, Design Criteria, Simulated Testing Criteria, and Acceptance Test Requirements. 
I was wondering in the graphic design world that there's anything similar to this? I have very little experience in this domain so any advice will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Usually no. But thing is soft designer get paid regardless while engineers dont. And also the requirement gathering is a internal engineering task so engineers do it for other engineers. A designer could do that for a design team not for you

Answer (score -2):

**YES THERE IS A SOLUTION**
If you want to collaborate with the UI/UX designer(S), i would STRONGLY suggest that you guys start using **Adobe XD** Its a FREE wireframing software from Adobe and by using it you guys will have visual ideas of what the app or website should look like and perform like.

Have a look into it and see if it works for your team.

Comment: Whatever tool is used doesn't directly answer what OP is asking (also doesn't matter where wireframes or visuals are created). Please [edit] to explain more HOW can Xd (or any other tool) help OP in this case.